# O spread do ECMAScript …arr é um operador?

Tags: javascript, terminologia, característica-linguagem, operadores, ecmascript

Já vi artigos fazendo referência ao *spread* como "sintaxe spread" e como "operador spread" (como por exemplo [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)).

Entendo que um "operador" é "uma função que recebe argumentos e retorna um único resultado" e não parece ser isso que o *spread* faz. Por exemplo:

```
let arr = [1, 2];
let var1 = ...arr;
```

A segunda linha falha e nada é atribuído a `var1`, se o *spread* fosse um operador, `...arr` deveria retornar alguma coisa e isto não acontece.

No ECMAScript faz mesmo sentido denominar o *spread* de "operador spread"?

Comment: O que você esperaria que acontecesse em `let var = ...arr` se "o spread *fosse* um operador", como cita?

Comment: Que retornasse algum valor, já que é dito um operador. Por exemplo, retornasse `[1, 2]`.

Comment: Mas ele não faz isso, em nenhum momento. Por que um operador iria retornar uma lista de uma lista? Seria o mesmo que não utilizá-lo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Se eu trocar por `let var1 = [...arr]` funciona.

Comment: Na verdade o ponto principal da dúvida é se o spread é ou não um operador por definição.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss O exemplo é apenas um teste para mostrar que não pode ser denominado como "operador".

Comment: A especificação define a sintaxe `...value` como um Object Initializer, que é uma expressão. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-object-initializer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [documentação que consideramos "oficial" fala em sintaxe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) não fala em operador.

Aí você pode estar pensando que viu na mesma documentação escrito que é operador conforme o *link* exposto. Mas não é a mesma. É uma tradução para o português, e nossa cultura é de fazer tudo mais ou menos, não temos preocupação com qualidade e não ligamos para os detalhes que fazem algo estar certo ou errado. Alguém pegou pra traduzir a documentação, foi arrogante e achou que sabia traduzir para algo melhor que o original, mudando o sentido e gerando confusão. Por isso sempre aconselho as pessoas olharem o que está em inglês, quase 100% das vezes está melhor. Tem coisas sobre o Brasil que está melhor em inglês. Especificamente esta tradução é muito ruim, um verdadeiro desserviço.

A versão original deixa claro que é uma sintaxe e que faz algo diferente de um operador. Esta sintaxe só pode ser usada em determinados lugares e não em qualquer lugar onde um operador pode estar, inclusive o que ele resulta não é um valor e sim uma outra sintaxe, por isso não tem como isto ser um operador. O resultado é uma sintaxe com uma lista dos elementos do objeto enumerável usado como argumento do *spread*. Não retorna um *array* ou outro objeto enumerável, não retorna um valor único, retorna algo para ser preenchido sintaticamente onde cabe, ou seja, em uma chamada de função ou um literal de *array*.

De fato a documentação está na seção de operadores, o que é um erro, mas talvez não acharam onde deveria entrar. E a [especificação](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html) é muito fraca com relação a isto e em uma introdução informal ela fala em operador, em nenhum outro lugar sequer dá a entender que seja um operador.

A dúvida é boa e levanta algo curioso. C++ assim como EcmaScript são criadas por comitês e os participantes institucionais não são tão diferentes entre eles (as pessoas são), e raramente você vê alguma coisa falha ou ambiguidade na especificação de C++, fora que estão se preparando para usar código "provando" o que está na especificação. JavaScript nasceu de uma forma bem torna e mambembe, e parece que a evolução não está tendo com tanto cuidado assim. Quando há uma falha boba dessas será que estão tomando decisões com parcimônia?

De qualquer forma a especificação mostra que esta sintaxe só pode ser usada em inicializadores de objeto, *array* e listas de argumentos. Um operador não tem essa restrição toda. Sua análise está correta.

Podemos dizer de certa forma que ele é uma macro expansão encrustada na linguagem. Então o que `...arr` faz é **expandir** para um código equivalente a `1, 2` (atenção ao fato que não é um valor assim, é um texto para o código). Exatamente o mecanismo usado para isto eu não sei e não ficou claro na especificação se tem um "jeito certo" de fazer, por isso acredito que cada implementação pode fazer como quiser e ter uma espécie de `eval()` aplicado ali, ou que todos os lugares que aceitam essa sintaxe possam ser trocadas por algo diferente compatível com o que já existe, etc. Então `let var1 = ...arr;` resultaria em `let var1 = 1, 2;` e esta sintaxe é inválida, isto não existe em EcmaScript. E por isso que dentro de `[]` ou `()` funciona, afinal `[1, 2]` ou `(1, 2)` são sintaxes válidas em certos contextos, ainda que pode não ser o que deseja fazer.

Eu fiz minha parte de [melhorar a tradução](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator$revision/1551130) para refletir o que estava no original. Não quero tirar a referência a operadores sem mudar na original em inglês e para fazer algo tão radical eu gostaria de discutir o assunto antes e não atropelar, mas ainda não sei como fazer isto.

Comment: Reposta muito boa e obrigado por ter melhorado a tradução do MDN web docs.